# Criteria API: can I use Criteria with unidirectional ManyToMany association?

Tags: hibernate, many-to-many, associations, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-criteria

I have `User` entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;
```

And `Project` entity, which has unidirectional `ManyToMany` association with `User`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "projects")
public class Project {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable
    private List<User> users;
```

And then I would like to get all users assigned to specified project. Simplest way is to ask `GroupDAO` about project by ID and then get users in this project. But I think this is not his responsibility, `UserDAO` should take care about `User`. Is there any chance, with `Criteria` interface, to get combine `Project` entity with `User` to achieve this? I tried the following:

```
@Override
public List<User> getByProjectId(Long projectId) {
    Criteria criteria = createCriteria(User.class);
    criteria.setFetchMode("project", FetchMode.JOIN);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("project.id", projectId));
    criteria.setResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
    List<User> users = (List<User>) criteria.list();
    return users;
}
```

But it still "need" `Project` association in `User` entity. I would be happy if anybody decides to help me - thank you in advance for your time.
**Update:** I probably found working but not elegant solution, but still I am asking you for help. **Solution:**

I also tried the following:

```
public List<User> getByProjectId(Long projectId) {
    Query query = getCurrentSession().createQuery("from User as user right 
        join Project project where project.id=:projectId");
    query.setLong("projectId", projectId);
    List users = query.list();
    return users;
}
```

but I got `org.hibernate.QueryException: outer or full join must be followed by path expression [from entities.User as user right join Project project where project.id=:projectId]`. Then I gave up and decided to ask `ProjectDAO` about users in project:

```
@Override
public List<User> getUsersInProject(Long projectId) {
    Criteria criteria = createCriteria(Project.class);
    criteria.createAlias("users", "u");
    criteria.setResultTransformer(Transformers.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("id", projectId));

    List resultList = criteria.list();
    List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
    for (Object result: resultList){
        Map resultMap = (Map) result;
        users.add((User) resultMap.get("u"));
    }
    return users;
}
```

And it seems to be ok, but still I would be happy if some of you would look at my problem to solve it in more elegant way - thanks in advance to all viewers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also tried the following:

```
public List<User> getByProjectId(Long projectId) {
    Query query = getCurrentSession().createQuery("from User as user right 
        join Project project where project.id=:projectId");
    query.setLong("projectId", projectId);
    List users = query.list();
    return users;
}
```

but I got `org.hibernate.QueryException: outer or full join must be followed by path expression [from entities.User as user right join Project project where project.id=:projectId]`. Then I gave up and decided to ask `ProjectDAO` about users in project:

```
@Override
public List<User> getUsersInProject(Long projectId) {
    Criteria criteria = createCriteria(Project.class);
    criteria.createAlias("users", "u");
    criteria.setResultTransformer(Transformers.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("id", projectId));

    List resultList = criteria.list();
    List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
    for (Object result: resultList){
        Map resultMap = (Map) result;
        users.add((User) resultMap.get("u"));
    }
    return users;
}
```